# *NgFor não está percorrendo o array no html

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript, pagamento-online

Estou consumindo a API da Wirecard para realizar uma integração, no momento em que tento retornar todos os cartões que estão cadastrados para um cliente, eu consigo obtê-los apenas no menu console.log, quando tento percorrer este array e mostrar os seus dados no meu html, simplesmente não aparece nada. Gostaria de ajuda para ver no que estou errando.

```
  this.pacientesSubscription = this.pacienteProvider.buscarPacientes().subscribe(result => {
  result.filter(data => {
    if (data.uidUsuario == this.usuarioLogadoUid) {
      this.paciente = data;
      this.idUsuario = data.idMoip; //Id do usuário na plataforma moip
      this.moip.customer.getOne(data.idMoip) //Vou na api da moip e retorno o cliente que possui este id
        .then((response => {
          this.qtdCartoes = response.body.fundingInstruments.length;
          this.formasPagamento = response.body.fundingInstruments; //Retorna todas as formas de pagamento (debito, credito, etc...)
          let cartoesDeCredito: Array<any> = [];
          cartoesDeCredito = this.formasPagamento.filter(result => {
            return result.method == 'CREDIT_CARD'; //Filtro apenas os cartões de crédito
          })
          this.cartoesCredito = cartoesDeCredito.map(data => {
            return data.creditCard; //Mapeio o array de cartões de crédito e crio um array de objetos
          })
          console.log(this.cartoesCredito); //Aqui me retorna normalmente o array de objetos (no caso cartões)
        })).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
  })
})
```

O retorno do meu console.log é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu html é o seguinte:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let teste of cartoesCredito">{{teste}}</ion-item>
   <div class="sem-cartao" *ngIf="qtdCartoes == 0">
     <img src="../../assets/icons/credit-card.svg" class="imagem-sem-cartao" 
     />
     <p style="white-space: pre-line; font-size: 1.4rem;">
     Nenhuma forma de pagamento cadastrada, clique abaixo para cadastrar uma 
     forma de pagamento e utilizar os nossos
     serviços
     </p>
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A minha view, não retorna nada conforme pode ser visto aqui:

Comment: Já tentou colocar o resultado na view, como texto, apenas para debug: {{ cartoesCredito | json}}

Comment: Olhando melhor, talvez a sua var teste devesse ser assim: {{ teste.brand }}

Comment: Se faço {{cartoesCredito | json}} me retorna apenas isso [].

Comment: E mesmo colocando o teste.brand ainda não aparece nada

Comment: estranho, consegue prover um pouco mais de informações da sua classe?

Comment: Coloque toda a classe do componente

Comment: Pessoal, estranhamente agora apareceu. Honestamente não sei o que era, pois é o código que uso habitualmente em todos os projetos. Mas agradeço muito a ajuda e o tempo de vocês para responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testei novamente aqui e agora rodando no próprio dispositivo e não no navegador. No dispositivo funciona normalmente, o único problema em questão parece ser no navegador que demorou aproximadamente uns 40 minutos para aparecerem as informações, enfim não sei o que é e o que foi. Mas de qualquer forma agora está funcionando normalmente. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.